# normed space little exercise

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$(X,K)$ a normed space
$E$ is a subspace of $X$.

if $\exists x_0 \in X$ that $||x_0||=d(x_0,E)=1$ then show

$$||e+\lambda x_0||\geq\frac{||e||}{2}\quad \forall e\in E \quad \forall\lambda\in K $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $d(\lambda x_0,E) = |\lambda|$ and hence $\|e+\lambda x_0\| \ge |\lambda|$ (this is the key element here).

Also, $\|e+\lambda x_0\| \ge \|e\|-|\lambda| $ (always true if $\|x_0\| = 1$).

Combining gives:
$\|e+\lambda x_0\| \ge \max (\|e\|-|\lambda|, |\lambda|) = \frac{\|e\|}{2}+ \max (\frac{\|e\|}{2}-|\lambda|, |\lambda|-\frac{\|e\|}{2}) \ge \frac{\|e\|}{2}$.

(So, in fact, $\|e+\lambda x_0\| \ge \frac{\|e\|}{2}+ ||\lambda|-\frac{\|e\|}{2}|$.)

Comment: What is $\|x_0\|$?

Answer (score 1):

The problem reduces to showing that if $\|x_0\| = 1$, $d(x_0,E) = 1$, $e \in E$,  and $\|e\| = 1$, then $\|e + \lambda x_0\| \ge \dfrac 12$ for all scalars $\lambda$.

If $|\lambda| \ge \dfrac 12$ then  $\displaystyle ||e + \lambda x_0\| = |\lambda| \cdot \| \frac{e}{\lambda} + x_0 \| \ge |\lambda| \ge \dfrac 12$
because $-\dfrac{e}{\lambda} \in E$.

On the other hand, if $|\lambda| < \dfrac 12$ then $\displaystyle \|e + \lambda x_0\| \ge \|e\| - \|\lambda x_0\| \ge 1 - |\lambda| > \dfrac 12$.

Comment: Why the problem reduces to showing this? I don not understand, please show me why,  thank you very much!

Comment: If $e = 0$ the inequality is trivial. If $e \not= 0$ you can define write the inequality as $||e/||e|| + (\lambda/||e||)x_0\| \ge \frac 12$. The right hand-side has the form $||f + \mu x_0\|$ where $||f|| = 1$ and $\mu$ is a scalar.